# How to read an audio file from IsolatedStorage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I have an audio file stored in `IsolatedStorage`..

I want to access it by calling a method of another class:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isolatedStorage.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {

        return fileStream;
    }
}
```

now when I call that method this way:

```
var fileStream = Musics.TryGetMusic("DaDaDa.mp3");
musicMediaElement.SetSource(fileStream);
musicMediaElement.Play();
```

I get an error saying it cannot read a closed file.

The cause is that I'm using `using` statement and the file is closed when I call `Play()`.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because, I presume yo call it, like

```
.... 

 using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isolatedStorage.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
 {    
     return fileStream;
 }
....
```

After exiting from the `using` statement, `fileStream` instance will be disposed.

To resolve this issue should be enough to not use `using` here,but instead track that instance lifetime and call dispose manually in appropriate place.

Comment: thanks @Tigran. How can I dispose it manually while that is a method of another class (helper) `Musics.TryGetMusic()` and I have not access to it anymore?

Comment: @user2799350: You return it to caller. So caller can take care of tracking it.

Comment: So in my question above, I should dispose later `var fileStream =...`.

Comment: @user2799350: exactly. when you finish using it and you no more need it (in your case probably after Play(..)), call dispose on it.